# Check if JSON has more than 2 arrays in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the best way to check if the json has more than 2 arrays.

This is an example of the JSON
So the JSON can have 2 cases, only one, and 2 arrays.

One

```
 "Type": "Jambli",
 "Assets": [
               {
                    "url": "urlHere",
               }
            ],
```

Two

```
"Type": "Glorie",
"Assets": [
                {
                    "url": "urlHere",
                },
                {
                    "url": "urlHere",
                }
            ],
```

I'm trying to use something like this

```
assets = json["Assets"]; //in json dart
```

```
sbuild(item[index].assets),
```

then

```
  if (a.Lenght <= 1) {
    child = Positioned(

//didn't work
```

```
  if (a <= 1) {
    child = Positioned(

//didn't work
```

```
  if (a != 1) {
    child = Positioned(

//didn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate `json["Assets"]` as a List type. Then, you can directly get the length attribute.

`assets = json["Assets"] as List<Map<String, String>>`

Writing the type of the List might not be necessary, however. In case you might not get a List for `assets`, try using a 'try-catch' block with a Cast Error being caught.

After this, you can get the length attribute by using `assets.length`.